# Selecting only rows from master table where subtable rows fulfill a condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my *image classification software* there are tables `result` and `image`.
**One result** can contain **many images**.
Each image may be classified as **positive** using value 'P' or **negative** 'N' in the column `image.preclassification`

A result, where more images are positive IS positive.

I want to select only positive results.

After reading PostgreS Documentation for hours I came to such solution which scares me:

```
WITH tmp AS (
SELECT result.result_id AS res, image.result_id , Count( image.preclassification ) AS ImgAll,  
SUM(
CASE image.preclassification 
  WHEN 'P' THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END
) AS ImgPos

from result, image
WHERE result.result_id = image.result_id
GROUP BY result.result_id, image.result_id
)
SELECT result_id
FROM tmp
WHERE ImgPos > ImgAll/2
```

My question is, is there a easier solution/approach for such (ihmo very common) problem?

**EDIT:** Explanation

First I create a temporary table with columns containing count of positive images and count for all images of a result. In next step I select only rows there the count of positive images is more then the half of all images. My first idea was to use `ImgPos > ImgAll/2` in the first `WHERE` statement and not using `WITH`-clause. But it didn't work as ImgPos, ImgAll were reported as unknown columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clever query.  But I think you can simplify it:

```
select r.result_id
from result r join
     image i
     on r.result_id = i.result_id
group by r.result_id
having sum(case when i.preclassification = 'P' then 1 else 0 end) >
       sum(case when i.preclassification = 'N' then 1 else 0 end);
```

You can also write this as:

```
select r.*
from (select r.result_id,
             sum(case when i.preclassification = 'P' then 1 else 0 end) as NumPos,
             sum(case when i.preclassification = 'N' then 1 else 0 end) as NumNeg
      from result r join
           image i
           on r.result_id = i.result_id
      group by r.result_id
     ) r
where NumPos > NumNeg;
```

Comment: +1 Great, thank you! Both work fine! (only had to replace image by i in 3rd,4th line in 2nd version). I think I'll take your first proposal as it looks easier :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do something like these two queries:

Take 1:

```
select *
from result r
join ( select t.result_id
       from result t
       join image  i  on i.result_id = t.result_id
       group by t.result_id
       having sum(case i.preclassification when 'P' then 1 else 0 end ) >
              sum(case i.preclassification when 'N' then 1 else 0 end )
     ) s on s.result_id = r.result_id
```

Take 2:

```
select r.*, p.frequence as positives , n.frequency as negatives
from result r
join      ( select t.result_id , count(*) as frequency
            from result t
            join image  i on i.result_id = r.result_id
                         and i.preclassification = 'P'
          ) p on r.result_id = p.result_id
left join ( select t.result_id , count(*) as frequency
            from result t
            join image  i on i.result_id = r.result_id
                         and i.preclassification = 'N'
          ) n on n.result_id = r.result_id
where p.frequency > coalesce( n.frequency, 0 )
```

The inner join on the positives derived table is because you have to have at least one positive for a result to be positive; the outer join on the negatives derived table is because you don't have to have any negatives at all.

Comment: +1: interesting, thanks! I've fixed 1st example and it works, but couldn't get 2nd to run.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is - just to map "positive" to positive and "negative" to negative :)

```
select r.result_id
from result as r
    inner join image as i on r.result_id = i.result_id
group by r.result_id
having sum(case i.preclassification when 'P' then 1 when 'N' then -1 end) > 0
```

Comment: +1: cool! works also. I'm glas I've asked this question. I've learnt a lot from all the answers :-)